# read raw input lines and output single array

Tags: json, jq, ls

I have a directory with files in it. I would like to create an array from that list of files. I thought it would be pretty easy, like:

```
ls mydir | jq -R '[.]'
[
  "file1"
]
[
  "file2"
]
[
  "file3"
]
```

The only thing I could figure out is this:

```
ls mydir | jq -sR '[split("\n")[]|select(.|length>0)]'
[
  "file1",
  "file2",
  "file3"
]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What are you looking to do with the array?

Comment: i am merging the contents of each file in that directory. each file is known as a dataset. the dataset name is the filename. so, once these files are merged, i am injecting metadata into that merge which declares which datasets comprises this merge. that injection is this array.  so, two things.  merging contents, injecting dataset origin metadata. the files have all been created by me, they have predictable filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to be extra careful in dealing with Unix filenames in general. They can contain almost any character in a filename, including whitespace, newlines, commas, pipe symbols, and pretty much anything else you'd ever try to use as a delimiter except NUL. Your best bet is to separate the names with the NUL character, which is the only character that can't be part of a valid filename and split on it with `jq`

Use the native shell `printf` to separate entries on `\0` and delimit it back

```sh
printf '%s\0' * | jq -Rn 'inputs | split("\u0000")'
```

or for just files

```sh
for file in *; do 
  [ -f "$file" ] && printf '%s\0' "$file"
done | jq -Rn 'inputs | split("\u0000")'
```

Comment: ls mydir | jq -nR '[inputs]'

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` opens up other possibilities:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 |
  jq -Rs 'split("\u0000") | map(sub("./";""))'
```

Comment: thanks @peak, the inputs is what was illuding me.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Slightly simpler than what you have:

```bash
ls mydir | jq -sR 'split("\n")[0:-1]'
```